# The capacity of a leather Quiver

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My hunters were constantly running out of bolts. A quick Google led me to [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/dwarffortress/comments/2frbju/hunters_running_out_of_ammunition) where someone posted that maximum capacity of a quiver was 15, but he was not sure. He also mentioned that use metal bolts to kill the animal in few hits. Its ok, but the question arises:

- what is the capacity of a leather quiver ?
- can a hunter/marksdwarf hold more number of quivers to maximise the amount of the bolts he can hold ?

Comment: I remember that in a previous version the behaviour was that dwarves would carry one stack of ammo, regardless of the size. I am not sure about the current version though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the capacity of a leather quiver ?

Certainly not 15; all metal bolts made in the fortress have a size of 25 (no data on bone and wood bolts, as I don't bother with them). I'm unsure if a max really exists, as there's no data that I could find online; more science is required. What I've seen from personal observation:

- Migrant hunters have arrived with stacks larger than 25. The largest stack I've ever seen is 47.
- Hunters and military marksdwarves reliably pick up the ammo assigned to them, sometimes over the constraints in the military > ammo screen (ie: a squad has 250 bolts assigned, each soldier gets 25, some have no issues picking 30 or more)

Also, to reference a comment, picking bolts is *not* restricted to a single stack: quivers will cheerfully be filled with full stacks, incomplete stacks, and 'stacks' of single bolts which have been fired and retrieved, often all at the same time.

[EDIT] Science incoming: I increased a squad's assigned bolts to 50 per dwarf; they were picked with no difficulties. Higher numbers pending.

[EDIT#2] **There seems to be a max capacity for leather quivers in fortress mode: 50.** After one and a half in-game year with bolts set to 100 per dwarf, none were seen to pick up more than that number.

> can a hunter/marksdwarf hold more number of quivers to maximise the amount of the bolts he can hold ?

No hunter or marksdorf has ever picked more than one quiver, and quivers can't be directly assigned to marksdorfs in the military screen (it comes with the posting, basically), so the answer would be no.

Adventure mode can use multiple quivers, but that's likely not relevant to fortress mode.

Comment: BTW: all this happened on v 0.42.05.